# How suitable is MatLab's $\text{eig}()$ function for large scale computations?

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra

I've been wondering about MatLab's $\text{eig}()$ function and how suitable it is for certain situations. Say we have a system with a very large number of interacting particles and thus a very large matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$. Is the $\text{eig}()$ function efficient in such a situation and if not, how are such eigenvalues problems typically solved? What are the best methods for such situations and how do they improve on the performance of the $\texttt{eig}$ function?

Comment: What is a typical value of N ? very important : ** Are your matrices sparse** ? @Moo Matlab will give almost instantly the eigenvalues for a 500-by-500 matrix with a very very good accuracy (unless the matrix is very ill-conditionned).

Comment: @JeanMarie: Of course any numerical approach is going to have issues depending on the problem and there are **always** pathological problems that will make it fail. It looks like eigs has some parameters for these cases like if eigs fails to converge for a given matrix, increase the number of Lanczos basis vectors by increasing the value of opts.p. As secondary options, adjusting the maximum number of iterations, opts.maxit, and the convergence tolerance, opts.tol, can also help with convergence behavior. The tool hopefully tells you such things when it is not converging.

Comment: You might get better feedback on this at the [Computational Science Stack Exchange](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com). However, I'd be more specific as to your actual problem and what you mean by "large".

Comment: As @horchler as said, you haven't answered about size $N$ and the sparsity (less say than 5% of nonzero entries) of your matrices ? Matlab uses efficiently matrices'sparsity.

Comment: @Moo thanks for your precise commentary. By the way, do you know a reference dealing with the algorithms used by Matlab, not only in Linear Algebra : for example, I am looking for the algorithms Matlab uses for the computation of elementary transcendental functions.

Comment: @horchler By large I mean $N$ could be over 10,000.